# WPF Data Context c#

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, user-controls, datacontext

I'm trying to understund how datacontex is passed to usercontrols.

I have 2 classes:

```
    public class OuterClass
    {
            public InnerClass inner {get; set;}
    }

    public class InnerClass
    {
            public void targetFun()
            {
                    //do something
            }
    }
```

And the Main Window class

```
    public class MainWindow: Window
    {
            public OuterClass outer {get; set;}

            //...
    }
```

In the main window xaml file the DataContext is set to be the Outer class

```
    <Window <!-- Properties --> >
            <Grid DataContext="{Binding outer}">
                    <MyControl DataContext="{Binding inner}">
                    <!-- Here I do more stuff from outer class -->
            </Grid>
    </Window>
```

And this would be the definition of my UserControl

```
    <UserControl x:Class="my:MyControl">
            <Grid>
                    <TextBlock MouseDown="targetFun">Click me!</TextBlock>
            </Grid>
    </UserControl>
```

When I try to compile I get the error that the function `"targetFun"` does not exist in `'MyControl'` it means that the compiler does not realize im trying to set the context in inner. How do I do that.

Sorry for the simple code I can't show the real one but this is pretty much what i'm doing.
Thanks!

Edit: Typo

Comment: your binding path should be outer.inner <MyControl DataContext="{Binding outer.inner}">

Comment: It would be nice to be able to bind events to view model methods like that.

Comment: @IAbstract: that feature isn't built into WPF, but there are ways to accomplish the same thing with attached properties (e.g. "behaviors" or similar extensions to WPF).

Comment: see e.g. eventtocommandbehavior for the targetfun binding

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In WPF, `Binding` uses the control's `DataContext` as its context. For example,

```
<Grid DataContext="{Binding outer}">
    <local:MyControl DataContext="{Binding inner}">
```

`inner` is a member of the value of `outer`. This example is a little funny because at the time when `{Binding inner}` is evaluated (or whatever), the `DataContext` of that `Grid` is `outer`, inherited from its parent. But then the binding sets it to something else. I avoid such things; I'm taking your word for it that it works at all.

Anyhow. Where's the binding on `MouseDown` here?

```
<TextBlock MouseDown="targetFun">Click me!</TextBlock>
```

Nowhere. That's not a regular property that you're binding a viewmodel property to, hence the `TextBlock`'s `DataContext` is irrelevant. That's an event, and are (or should be) giving it an event handler. Events are different (because they are, that's why). Since there's no `{Binding ...}`, it's not looking for a property of the `DataContext`; it's looking for an event handler method on the codebehind class. Delete `="targetFun"` there, type `="` after `MouseDown`, and it'll prompt you to create an event handler on the codebehind class.

You can call `targetFun()` like this in the event handler:

```
private void TextBlock_MouseDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    ((sender as FrameworkElement).DataContext as InnerClass)?.targetFun();
}
```

Comment: You should not be using `as` here. That operator is useful if you are going to then check the result for `null`. But you don't. If the object is ever the wrong type, then you'll get a `NullReferenceException` instead of the diagnostically much more useful `InvalidCastException`. And of course, if you're sure the object will always be the right type, a direct cast is more appropriate and efficient anyway.

Comment: @PeterDuniho It's funny, I just wrote a variant with direct casts, with an explanation of how that was more correct but in this case even more unreadable. I was about to click "Submit" when I realized my explanation needed another revision. At that moment my entire being was overwhelmed by a limitless, indescribable weariness of soul, amounting almost to despair -- and I decided not to bother. You're probably right but this is less unreadable.